# Amazon SQS - Requeue and delete message functionality

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Folks,

We are running our application under high load. We are trying to use requeue functionality of amazon DLQ.

The code we are using is below

```
public void requeueMessage(String queueName, Message message) {
    try {
        String queueUrl = getQueueURL(queueName)
        this.amazonSQS.deleteMessage(queueUrl, message.getReceiptHandle());
    } catch (AmazonClientException var4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Delete failed");
    }

    sendMessageAWS(queueName, message.getBody(), buildMessageBody(message));
}
```

We see that under high load deleteMessage is executing successfully for same message multiple times and same message enqued twice while second one fails with below exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: X-requeue-of= . 
{StringValue: 10090,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],DataType: String} and X- 
requeue-of={StringValue:10091,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],DataType: String}
```

Comment: Is this the deadletter for a FIFO SQS Queue?

Comment: Yes this is a dead letter for Normal SQS queue (We have two queues actually one is normal queue and other is dead letter for normal)

Comment: Not a First In First Out queue though? If It's FIFO you can't have multiple entries with the same key like its saying.

Comment: true but we are deleting the message first as it is FIFO then we try to enqueue and it fails as message is having same key.

Comment: Would it be better to just increase the number of retries and the visibility timeout rather than re-queueing over and over?